# Using SQL*Loader to parse non-uniform data that does not match 1:1 from data file to table, in a conditional manner

Tags: regex, oracle, sql-loader

I need to use SQL Loader to get some data from a .csv file into a single table in an Oracle database.  The data is unfortunately non-uniform, and the only way I know how to approach this is to case/conditional it through all the variations in format, but I'm unable to find a simple guide to using SQL Loader in such a procedural and conditional manner.

Here's my target table (primary key and other fields eliminated for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE students (
Year           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
Semester       VARCHAR2(1),
department     VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
course_number  NUMBER NOT NULL,
course_session VARCHAR2(3));
```

And here's the first few rows of my input data:

```
 2002-3,X52.9418.001
 2002,X52.9418.001
 20023,X52.9418.001
```

Here's the breakdown.  Year and semester are part of the first "field" in this comma-separated data file.  However the data in this field maps to two columns (Year and Semester).  That is:

```
2002-3 --> Year: 2002, Semester: 3
2002   --> Year: 2002, Semester: NULL
20023  --> Year: 2002, Semester: 3
```

department, course_number, and course_session make up the next "field" of this data file:

```
X52.9418.001 --> department: X52, course_number: 9418, course_session: 001
```

The logic is simple:

- If first field is in the format of ####, those numbers go to Year, Semester is Null.
- If first field is in the format of #####, the first four go to Year, the fifth goes to Semester.
- If first field is in the format of ####-#, split on "-", left portion to Year, right portion to Semester.
- Second field should be split on ".", the first result going to department, the second result going to course_number, and the third result going to course_session.

The only way I know how to approach this problem for the first column for example is with three regex's in three conditional blocks.  Any records not matching those three regex's should go to the BAD file so I can re-evaluate and potentially add more regex's to accommodate more formats.  But I can't seem to find any examples or guides that match this train of thought --- maybe I'm on the complete wrong path?

**This is part of an ungraded exercise** to get familiar with SQL Loader, and as such, all coding must be done in the SQL Loader's control file.  In other words, I can't use a programming language to clean the data file first, and I can't use external tables.

Answer (score 0):

This control file worked for me, nothing was moved to BAD file.
I put loading Semester field at the end, otherwise it didn't work.

```
load data
  infile 'c:\doc\stud.csv'
  log yes
  into table students
  fields terminated by "."
  trailing nullcols
  ( 
    Year terminated by ',' "substr(:Year, 1, 4)",
    department,
    course_number,
    course_session,
    Semester "ltrim(substr(:Year, 5, 2), '-')"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the fields as BOUNDFILLER, which tells SQL*Loader don't look for a column that matches the name, but save it for future expressions.  Then, use them in expressions for each real field:

```
LOAD DATA
infile mydata.dat
truncate
INTO TABLE students
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(
 FIELD1 BOUNDFILLER,
 FIELD2 BOUNDFILLER,
 year            "substr(:FIELD1, 1, 4)",
 semester        "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:FIELD1, '[^-]+', 5)",
 department      "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:FIELD2, '([^.]*)(.|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)",
 course_number   "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:FIELD2, '([^.]*)(.|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1)",   
 course_session  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:FIELD2, '([^.]*)(.|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1)"
)
```

year - Use the first 4 characters

semester - starting at position 5, match zero or more characters that are not a dash.

dept/course_number/course_session - Parse the field on periods, returning the first, second or third occurrence of 1 or more characters that are not a period, which are followed by a period or the end of the field as appropriate.